# Android Vibrator on Samsung

Tags: android

I have an issue with Android Vibrator. Basically, I have only one Singletone - scoped class incapsulating the android.os.Vibrator in a way, that it has two methods

```
startVibrating() {
if (VERSION.SDK_INT < VERSION_CODES.O) {
        vibrator.vibrate(PATTERN, 0);
      } else {
        vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createWaveform(PATTERN, 0));
      }
} 

stopVibrating() {
 vibrator.cancel();
}
```

The issue is that on some Samsung devices the Vibrator stops when the phone screen is turned off even I have a WakeLock for CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, we've got into the same situation.

According to Android docs:

> If your process exits, any vibration you started will stop.

And you would expect that if you have any CPU-related `WakeLock`, it should work fine. However, we found that Samsung devices on Android 6 and Android 7 stop the `Vibrator` in some other cases too. For example, each time when the screen is turned off using `PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK`, even if you take some other wake lock explicitly.

The good news that Samsung stops the `Vibrator` but it does not prohibit it from the future starts.

We've ended up with the next workaround:

When the screen goes off, the current activity gets `onStop()` call. So, we check if we should vibrate on that moment, and if we do, we simple start the `Vibrator` again. Maybe, not the best solution, but it works.